# Make medium_large images available to insert into post

Tags: images

Our post have a Max width of 768, so using the medium_large images is the preferred size for our authors. I ssumed since medium_large isnpart of core, this would be included but I don't see an easy way to activate that option.

Can this be activated as a new hook in our functions.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since I'm using a size already generated by WP, I just needed to add:

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'fresh_custom_sizes' );
function fresh_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
   return array_merge( $sizes, array(
      'medium_large' => __( 'Medium Large' ),
   ) );
}
```

Comment: I hope answer helped you to find out how to add custom sizes and then make them use in media uploading. Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235

Answer (score 1):

Please go through [link for details](https://wpshout.com/wordpress-custom-image-sizes/) I hope this may help to add your custom preferred size.

```
// Make sure featured images are enabled
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

// Add featured image sizes
add_image_size( 'featured-large', 640, 294, true ); // width, height, crop
add_image_size( 'featured-small', 320, 147, true );

// Add other useful image sizes for use through Add Media modal
add_image_size( 'medium-width', 480 );
add_image_size( 'medium-height', 9999, 480 );
add_image_size( 'medium-something', 480, 480 );

// Register the three useful image sizes for use in Add Media modal
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'wpshout_custom_sizes' );
function wpshout_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'medium-width' => __( 'Medium Width' ),
        'medium-height' => __( 'Medium Height' ),
        'medium-something' => __( 'Medium Something' ),
    ) );
}
```